# JPA caching using @QueryHints doesn't work if `saveAndFlush` method is called

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, spring-data-jpa, infinispan

I am using Hibernate3.6.6, spring-data-jpa1.6.4 and hibernate-infinispan3.6.6 as hibernate L2 cache provider.
I have enabled showSQL for hibernate to track how many queries are fired and how many calls are returned via cache.

If I call `saveAndFlush` method, then the following two `findbyKey` calls fire separate queries. However, if I comment the `saveAndFlush` method call, then only one query is fired to the database and the second result is presumable returned from the cache.

Can anyone please guide as to why this is happening?

```
final ABC abc = ABCRepository.saveAndFlush(ABC); //if commented only one query is fired for below two calls
final ABC savedABC = ABCRepository.findByKey(KEY1);
final ABC savedABC2 = ABCRepository.findByKey(KEY1);
```

Please let me know in case any more information is required.

Comment: I assume that the saveAndFlush probably updates or adds a new entity instance, which results in update timestamp being updated. After an update, Hibernate adds a little bit of leeway to the update timestamp, so if one or multiple queries happen very quickly after an update, then the query goes directly to DB. If you add some time between queries, e.g. 100ms, second one should come from cache. You can also check statistics of cache via session factory API...

Comment: @GalderZamarreño Thanks for the response. I will check by adding a delay. By the way, do you have any references for the clarification that you have provided? And can you share how to _check statistics of cache via session factory API_. Thanks!

Comment: @GalderZamarreño Adding a delay of 60 seconds works! I suspect there is a timeout somewhere which defaults to 60 seconds and then fetches it to the cache. Please add it as an answer so that I can accept it. Also please let me know how to check the statistics. Thanks!

Comment: 60 seconds sounds too much, did you try anything less than that? For cache statistics, see example code [here](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-simple-tutorials/blob/f506cc1b44951e2b70ab1f885f8fbbcce6e9b033/hibernate-cache-local/src/main/java/org/infinispan/tutorial/simple/hibernate/cache/local/InfinispanHibernateCacheLocal.java#L252).

Comment: @GalderZamarreño yes I tried a lot of options but at a minimum it takes 60 seconds. Thanks for your help. Cheers!

Comment: Hmmm, that's a little strange then. I'm not sure what could be causing it...